# using wget to mirror a website with path and subfolder that have the same name

Tags: linux, web-crawler, wget

I'm trying to make a mirror of a website, but the URLs include several paths that overlap when copied to files on disk in the normal `wget` way.  The problem manifests with URLs like `http://example.com/news` and `http://example.com/news/article1`.

Wget downloads these URLs as `/news` and `/news/article1`, but that means that the `/news` file is overwritten by a folder with the same name.

A proper static mirror would require that these two URLs be downloaded instead as `/news/index.html` and `/news/article1`.

I have tried to work around this problem by running `wget` twice and moving the files accordingly, but that hasn't worked well for me.  The `/news` path has links to `/news/article1` that need to be converted.  I'm using the `-k` option to convert links, but if I run `wget` twice, it doesn't convert the links between these unrelated downloaded files.

Here's my command:

```
wget -p -r -l4 -k -d -nH http://example.com
```

Here's an example of the work around that I've tried:

```
# wget once at first level (gets /news path but not /news/*)
wget -p -r -l1 -k -nH http://example.com

# move /news file to temp path
mv news /tmp/news.html

# wget again to get everything else (notice the different level value)
wget -p -r -l4 -k -nH http://example.com

# move temp path back to /news/index.html
mv /tmp/news.html news/index.html
```

In the above example, the links on the `/news` page that are supposed to point to `/news/article1` have not been converted.

Does anybody know how to work around this with `wget`?  Is there a different tool that would work better?

Comment: I guess (most) *Linux* filesystems don't allow a file and a directory of the same name anyway. Is it allowed to rename *files* to distinct them from directories?

Comment: @CommuSoft, YES! `wget` can rename HTML files to add the `.html` extension.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

The problem was my assumption that `/news/index.html` was the URL that I needed.  After closely reading the man page, I found that `-E (--adjust-extension)` solved my problem.  This flag forces `wget` to apply the `.html` extension onto all of the HTML files that it downloads.

Coupling that with `-k` to convert the links results in a 100% usable mirror that has all of the pages needed.

Here's an example map of the downloaded files and paths:

```
http://example.com/news           -->  /news.html
http://example.com/news/article1  -->  /news/article1.html
```

As a functional mirror, this is great.  Default webserver configurations (at least for Apache) seem to allow the path `http://sitemirror.com/news/article1` to load the `/news/article1.html` content.  However, it may be necessary for a rewrite to keep the `http:/sitemirror.com/news` path from displaying a 404 or index for the folder.  This should not be tough.

Oh, so here's my final `wget` command:

```
wget -p -r -l4 -E -k -nH http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you'd like to mirror an entire website with wget, and keep the naming scheme of the original website. That is, don't rename files by adding an .html extension.

A problem occurs if a file and directory conflict. The file will be overwritten when a directory is created.

How about this solution:

1. Mirror the website using `wget --mirror`
2. Then, as a second step, go back and download the problematic files. (Not all files.) So, if there was a wiki/ directory that had a main page, which should now be saved as "wiki/index.html" instead of plain "wiki/", download only that page.

The script below generates `index.html` files when there is a file/directory name overlap.

```
#!/bin/bash

function processdir() {
    website="https://www.example.com"
    echo "The dir name is $1";
    if [ -e $1/index.html ]; then
        echo "$1/index.html already exists"
    else
        echo "Downloading $website/$1 to $1/index.html"
        rm /tmp/index.html
        wget --quiet -O /tmp/index.html $website/$1
        if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
            echo "Download succeed. Copying file into place."
            echo "cp /tmp/index.html $1/index.html"
            cp /tmp/index.html $1/index.html
        else
            echo "Download failed."
        fi
        ls -al $1/index.html
    fi
}
export -f processdir
find . -type d -name '*' -exec /bin/bash -c 'processdir "$0"' {} \;
```